# Error ajax and PHP "Undefined index"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm a new to AJAX so I'm sorry if the solution is obvious.
I must send the dates to a MySQL table without refreshing the page and I currently have a problem doing this.

The code gives 
me the following error:

> " Notice: Undefined index: post in inserisci.php on line 6"

**FORM**

```
 <form id="form" class="form-horizontal shadow-z-1" action="includes/inserisci.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend style="text-align: center; position: relative; top: 8px;">Inserisci un Post</legend>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputTitle" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Titolo</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputText" name="titolo" placeholder="Scrivi qui il Titolo">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-2 control-label" name="testo">Messaggio</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <textarea id="messaggio"></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>

               <div class="form-group is-empty is-fileinput">
                    <label for="inputFile" class="col-md-2 control-label">File</label>

                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control" placeholder="Browse..." pmbx_context="19E61A0C-3526-4E51-8535-935982C4C335">
                      <input type="file" id="inputFile" multiple="" pmbx_context="1D2BCAEA-08CC-476A-8F4A-EF6BD51B9102">
                    </div>
                  <span class="material-input"></span></div>

            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById('modalposta').style.display = 'none';">Cancel</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick='send(); return false;' >Submit</button>
                    </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**INSERISCI.JS**

```
  function send(){
var content = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {titolo:titolo & post:testo}           
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })                                                 
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })                                                
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
}
```

**INSERISCI.PHP**

```
<?php

include('../core.php');

$titolo=$_REQUEST ['titolo'];
$post=$_REQUEST ['post'];

$sql = mysql_query("");

mysql_close();

?>
```

Other question.
I need to reload the content of this without refresh the page.

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php $sql = mysql_query("")  or die ("Nessun errore");
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            echo '

            <article class="flipper white-panel">
        <a class="flipcard flip" style="
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        top: -10px;
        z-index:1;
    "><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px;">bookmark</i></a>
        <div class="articolo">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sDLIAZD.png" alt="">

            <h4><a href="#">'.$row ['titolo'].'</a></h4>
            <p>'.Markdown($row ['contenuto']).'</p>
             <div class="pull-right">
                            <span class="label label-default">alice</span>
                            <span class="label label-primary">story</span>
                            <span class="label label-success">blog</span>
                            <span class="label label-info">personal</span>
                            <span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
                            <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
                          </div>
                          <hr>
                          </div>
        <div class="commenti">
            <ul class="comment-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="comment-img">

                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-text">

                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control inputcomment" placeholder="Lascia un Commento.."/>
                  </div>
      </article>
         ';
        }


    }
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Notes:**
>
> 1. Please do not use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated.
> 2. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks. Please make sure you address them.

That's a syntax error. That's not a valid JavaScript Object. Change your `data` object to:

```
data: {titolo:titolo, post:testo}
```

Also you need to close the `$.ajax` before you are using `.done`.

```
  var content = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {titolo:titolo & post:testo}           // Should be closed here.
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })                                                 // Should not be closed. Remove ;
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })                                                 // Should not be closed. Remove ;
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
  // });                                                Remove this!
```

If nothing works out, please change these lines:

```
$titolo = $_POST['titolo'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
```

And wait, did you get the values for those two?

```
var titolo = $('input[name="titilo"]').val();
var testo = $('input[name="testo"]').val();
```

Comment: Same problem. Undefined index: post in inserisci.php on line 6

Comment: You aren't closing the line: `$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {titolo:titolo & post:testo})

.done` Close it using `)` before `.done`.

Comment: @Master-Antonio There are lot of problems. Please address them. See the above answer.

Comment: @Master-Antonio Did you see the above answer?

Comment: @Master-Antonio Updated again for an ultimate solution.

Comment: @Master-Antonio Refer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/viZMv.png, http://www.softwareishard.com/firebug/introduction/net-panel/request-headers-thumb.png

Comment: Is right code of FORM? action="includes/inserisci.php" method="post" And onClick='send(); return false;

Comment: Ah!!! Change the code like this: `url: "includes/inserisci.php"` in your AJAX call.

Comment: @Master-Antonio You have a lot of errors. Main thing needed is the `Form Data` section in your screenshot.

Comment: @Master-Antonio Yeah for that only AJAX is used. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the data you are passing in your AJAX request is not a valid javascript object and you are not getting the variables from the form:

```
data: {titolo:titolo & post:testo}
```

You should instead do something like:

```
var titolo = $('form input[name="titolo"]').val();
var testo = $('form input[name="testo"]').val();
data: {
   titolo:titolo,
   post:testo
}
```

Also, as a side note, when accessing array elements, its not good form to put a space between the variable and the bracket. I'm surprised that even works.

```
$_REQUEST ['titolo']
```

Should be

```
$_REQUEST['titolo']
```

Comment: [That's not a JSON, but a JavaScript Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) FYI.

Comment: You are right. I was just working on something and for some reason that was in my head. Fixed it.

Comment: Ha ha. Moreover, I was coincidentally reading that so thought of sharing. `:)` No offence.

Comment: Same problem. Undefined index: post in inserisci.php on line 6

Comment: @Master-Antonio I updated my answer. I didn't realize you weren't grabbing the variables first. You are sending a `null` value and it gets discarded.

Comment: Nothing. Dont work.  var post = $('form [name="testo"]').val();

Comment: Is right code of FORM? action="includes/inserisci.php" method="post"  And onClick='send(); return false;'

Comment: Yes. You can use `console.log()` to test your javascript is getting run and to output the contents of variables. It is a valuable client side debugging tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ajax form submit, Update your form definition with

```
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal shadow-z-1" action="#" method="post">
```

use following updated javascript

```
function send() {
    var content = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: {
            titolo:  "Value for titolo",
            post: "Value for post"
        }
    }).done(function() {
        alert( "success" );
    }).fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    }).always(function() {
        alert( "complete" );
    });
}
```

Comment: I *believe* that might cause a W3C validation issue, `action="#"`.